# The application crashes in SetcontentView (My Activity), which uses my class extends Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I created a `class Sapper Button extends Button`, and buttons of this type are in the layout . In desiner window i see:

```
castom view SupperButton is not using the 2- or 3- argument. View constructors. XML attributes will not work.
```

And my app is crashed after starting of this layout at  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);`. Why and how to fix it?
Here is the beginning of my Activity:

```
package com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


    int numBombs;
    Button[][] fields;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        TextView numBombText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numBombText);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        numBombs = intent.getIntExtra("numBombs", 10);


        numBombText.setText("Number of bombs is: " + numBombs);
```

my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/numBombs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:paddingTop="5pt"
        android:paddingBottom="5pt"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numBombText"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="12sp">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/numBombs"
        android:id="@+id/lin123"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:paddingTop="5pt"
        android:paddingBottom="5pt"
        android:weightSum="1.0">
        <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
        <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#f1f1c8"
            android:textColor="#00ecfd"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#f1f1c8"
        android:textColor="#00ecfd"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

my Button class:

```
package com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SapperButton extends Button {

    private boolean isOpen = false;
    private boolean isBomb = false;
    private boolean isBlown = false;
   /*
        public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        }

    public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    */
    public SapperButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }




    public boolean isOpen()
    {
        return isOpen;
    }

public void setOpen(boolean open)
{
    isOpen = open;
}
public void setBomb(boolean bomb)
{
    isBomb = bomb;
}

public boolean getIsBomb()
{
    return isBomb;
}


public boolean isBlown()
{
    return isBlown;
}

public void setBlowned(boolean isBlowning)
{
    isBlown = isBlowning;
}
```

}

log of crashing:

```
03-26 19:03:58.874 31921-31921/com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper, PID:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper/com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.SapperButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:603)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:312)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1952)
at com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:312) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1952) 
at com.example.helen.mynewgamesapper.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:20) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have commented out the constructors in SapperButton that Android needs to use to create instances of that view when used in an XML layout.  Those are `the 2- or 3- argument constructors` that it's telling you about in the error message.  Uncomment them, check them for correctness, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor will be called when you inflate view form XML.

```
public SapperButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29